# Convert a tab delimited file into vector in r and use it to process

Tags: r, file, vector, row

I want to convert each row of tab delimited file (.txt extension into a vector) and use that vector for furthur processing and then store the results in another file . So far I have

```
 df <- read.csv("matrix_pvalues.txt")
head(df)
X1.00E.08.2.75E.45.7.15E.08
 1 1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t3.42E-05
 2 1.00E-23\t8.86E-42\t0.017703944
 3 1.00E-16\t1.75E-70\t0.0121
 4 1.00E-30\t1.20E-07\t1
 5 1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t0.004553174
 6 1.00E-23\t1.00E+00\t0.049965122
> df_vector<-as.vector(t(df))
> head(df_vector)
 [1] "1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t3.42E-05"    "1.00E-23\t8.86E-42\t0.017703944"
 [3] "1.00E-16\t1.75E-70\t0.0121"      "1.00E-30\t1.20E-07\t1"          
 [5] "1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t0.004553174" "1.00E-23\t1.00E+00\t0.049965122"
```

Any input will be helpful

Comment: have you tried `read.delim` since it is using `\t` as a delimiter... `read.csv` uses `','`.

Comment: can you paste `dput(head(df))`

Comment: you can manually set the `sep` argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the same number of values in each line:

```
DF <- read.delim(text="1.00E-08\t2.75E-45\t7.15E-08
1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t3.42E-05
1.00E-23\t8.86E-42\t0.017703944
1.00E-16\t1.75E-70\t0.0121
1.00E-30\t1.20E-07\t1
1.00E-18\t1.00E+00\t0.004553174
1.00E-23\t1.00E+00\t0.049965122", header=FALSE)
```

Notice I had to guess at the first row, but your read.csv assumes the first row contains column names so it tried to convert that data. Now each row can be extracted as a vector, e.g.:

```
DF[1, ]
#      V1       V2       V3
# 1 1e-08 2.75e-45 7.15e-08
```